# Child component life cycle in parent component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

I have a child component in a parent component. My question is: when will the child component be displayed in the code? Before a function in the parent finishes or after the statement of the variable is assigned. Please see the code below:

parent.component.html

```
<child-component *ngIf="show"> </child-component>
```

parent.component.ts

```
function(){
  this.show = true;
  this.anotherVariable = 5;
}
```

In the code above, when will the child component will be displayed? As soon as the statement  `this.show = true;` runs or after the function ends (which is after `this.anotherVariable = 5;`  statement).

Answer (score 2):

It will be shown on the next [change detection cycle](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) after `show` is set to `true`.

*Generally*, yes, that means immediately(ish) after the variable is changed.

Change detection is a large topic, read more about it here, but basically by changing any of your bound properties in the parent, you are likely invoking the change detector, which is notifying the child-component of their new values (the primary job of the CD).

To optimize this process, you should probably show your component as the last step of this transaction.

- https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/
- https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10
- https://medium.com/@bencabanes/angular-change-detection-strategy-an-introduction-819aaa7204e7

Comment: But In my code, I set storage class variable(which will be used via dependency injection )  after setting  show variable. And In child component at  ngOnInit   , I am reading this data. And I can manage to read this data. (so it means child view will be triggered after all codes in function executed) AM I wrong

Comment: Good question. The thing you have just described is more complex than the simple code you posted. Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56309844/edit) and post a real [mcve] so we can better understand. But like I said, change detection is complex.

Comment: That is a really interesting question. Without diving deep into the Angular internals, my guess is that the single-threaded rules of javascript say the function completes first.

Comment: @Jesse Provided that the function makes _only blocking_ calls (which is not yet clear), yes, the function would return from the execution stack first, however (see next):

Comment: @ozziem [`ngOnInit()`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) is called when the first `ngAfterContentChecked()` event is triggered (i.e., when bound properties change). So in all likelihood, by setting `this.anotherVariable` you are simply invoking the change detector, so it's not unexpected that you see your new value.

Comment: @msanford   the important point is this.show = true; not this.anotherVariable setting.  you may be right for  "ngOnInit() is called when the first ngAfterContentChecked() event is triggered (i.e., when bound properties change)"  but my question is still about this. When will it be triggered ? before the completely finish of function that involves the code that cause triggerring  ngAfterContentChecked() (In this example   this.show = true;)  or at the time that assigning  this.show = true;  so you do not answer my question still as far as I understand.

Comment: I tried a lot and tested @Jesse "Provided that the function makes only blocking calls (which is not yet clear), yes, the function would return from the execution stack first, however  "  I see that this is true for chrome. But just in cases , I moved this.show after other statements.

Comment: @ msanford  "function makes only blocking calls (which is not yet clear), yes, the function would return from the execution stack first,  "  yes It looks true in chrome.

Comment: But I strongly advice changing code like this:
function(){
  this.anotherVariable = 5;
  this.show = true;
}   Because if I am not wrong,  synchronise problem may cause and I SEE THAT If I put  this.show = true; first  the child  component is loading more slowly. But ofcourse I could not measure exactly